# What's the critical mass of elemental natural uranium?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

What's the critical mass of elemental (ie metallic), natural (ie unenriched) uranium? If this isn't possible at standard temperature and pressure, how could they be changed to make a critical mass? Eg, neutron reflectors or high pressures.

So I'm interested in whether there are any conditions under which unenriched metallic uranium could sustain a nuclear chain reaction.

Cheers.

The following is data about the physical qualities of uranium that might be relevant when discussing its possible critical mass.

- Approximate occurrence of natural uranium isotopes   U238 99.3%
  U235
  0.7%
- Assuming thermal neutrons, fission cross sections are   U238 0.0002
  barns   U235 583 barns
- Capture cross sections are   U238 2 barns   U235 99 barns
- Uranium density at room temperature is 19,100 kilograms per cubic meter.
- Atomic mass of uranium is 238.02891 u.

Comment: I think this is a neat question, but in its present form it won't work for us. You might enjoy reading the [Los Alamos Primer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Alamos_Primer).

Comment: Big picture, you need to know the average number of neutrons created per fission, then find the probability that a given neutron will cause another fission. This has two parts: the capture probability (which increases with mass) and the escape probability (which decreases with mass). At critical mass, the product of those two is 1. In natural uranium at STP, the capture probability is too large, so there is no critical mass.

Comment: Natural uranium can sustain a chain reaction (the [first reactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Pile-1) used natural uranium), but not easily. The neutrons from a fission event are fast neutrons. Your numbers are for thermal (slow) neutrons, so you need a moderator in the reactor core to slow the neutrons down (without absorbing them). That makes the calculation of a critical mass a bit useless as that depends on the moderator and on the spatial configuration of the core.

Comment: U-238 can effectively only fission with fast neutrons, but the [neutrons released by a U-238 fission are (on average) not fast enough to fission another U-238 nucleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-238), which prevents a fast neutron chain reaction in U-238.

Comment: @rob Heya, I tried editing the question to make it less like a homework question. I'd love to get it reactivated, as I'm still interested in this question.

Comment: @tobuslieven Have a look in the [help] to see whether your edit will put your question into the reopen queue --- it mayhave been too long for that to happen automatically.  If so, you might want to (politely) draw attention to your revised question in [chat] or on [meta].